# dlmread range with unlimited rows

Tags: octave

I'm reading a range of values from a csv-file:

```
M = dlmread(filename,delimiter,[R1 C1 R2 C2])
```

Is there any way to specify `R2` parameter as default or unknown? I want to read all the rows, but a limited number of columns.

```
R1=0,
C1=0,
R2=Unknown,
C2=15
```

Comment: you can set `R2 = ((2^31) - 1)`. This is the max logical indexing which octave 32bit can handle (afaik). But this is only a workaround. I've no better idea.